# MongoDB: Nested Query at unknown depth

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the following document. Is there a way to query for the Value of `name` at a unknown depth within `items`?

```
{
    name:"One",
    items:[
        {
            name:"Two",
            items:[
                {
                    name:"Three",
                    items:[]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"Four",
            items:[
                {
                    name:"Five",
                    items:[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For example, I would like to do

db.collection.find({name:"Three"},{"items.$"}) where I had no idea that "Three" was at the 3rd tier of items.

Comment: No, unless you want to use [Server-side JavaScript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/).

Comment: As a piece of advice: deeply nested documents usually are a sign that you should rethink your modelling.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - I am actually open to that, however the requirement is that I have a Hierarchy. Take the example of A Contains B and B contain C so therefore A has visibility to C. However C has no direct relationship to A. How do I get the full scope of what A can see without either multiple DB calls or a Nested Document

Comment: Have a deep look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/. Usually, the performance impact of deeply nested documents is worse than doing multiple queries on well defined and optimized models.

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this topic, I'm currently investigating a similar use case?

Comment: @gb2d unfortunately no. I had to abandon the idea. Basically you need to know where in the document your data is... Who would of thought  :/

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the url you provided is now dead; use this one instead: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/index.html