# How to search a specific key value of a highly nested collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having a highly nested MongoDB collection, the document inside the collection looks like below:

```
"item" : [
    {
        "id" : NumberLong(717), 
        "parentId" : NumberLong(710),
        "item" : [
            {
                "id" : NumberLong(718), 
                "parentId" : NumberLong(717)
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : NumberLong(719), 
        "parentId" : NumberLong(710),
        "item" : [
            {
                "id" : NumberLong(720), 
                "parentId" : NumberLong(719),
                 "item" : [
                     {
                         "id" : NumberLong(721), 
                         "parentId" : NumberLong(720)
                     }
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Every "item" is a list of "item"s, and each "item" is attached with a parentId. Is there a way that I can get all the documents which have parentId equals a specific number?

**Edit:** The collection is created by a Java class looks like:

```
public class Item {
    private long id;
    private long parentId;
    private List<Item> item;
}
```

So actually I can't specify the level by query like {"item.item.parentId" : "123"}.

Comment: Please add anything you have tried so far to the post and your expected response.

Comment: the query depends what level of parentID you want to use in your search criteria.
db.abc.find({'item.parentId':710}) this returns me result as well as db.abc.find({'item.item.parentId':717}) returns me results. so it depends what is your criteria to access and what level of digging you want to do

Comment: Also, can you give an example of actual document you are storing because there may be a way to simplify your schema design.

Comment: @satishchennupati actually the problem is that I might have unknown levels of parentId. The document is created by deserialization of a Java class called Item. There is a List<Item> as its field. So I get such a highly nested collection.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298464/query-nested-elements-from-unknown-number-of-arrays) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574725/mongodb-nested-query-at-unknown-depth) questions.

Comment: @arsendavtyan91 thanks!